# How to Calculate Variance with PowerBI DAX Waterfall Chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-custom-visuals

I've sifted through threads and videos trying examples, but I still seem to be stuck. Please help? DAX newbie here.

I have a data set with yearly sales with granularity by geography, device type, and another column with ~6 different technical specifications. I would like to display a dynamic waterfall chart that shows yearly changes in sales based on selected slicers/filters in the workbook.

1) Resolve in one step

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(Data[$]))-CALCULATE(SUM(Data[$]),PARALLELPERIOD(Data[Date],-1,YEAR))
```

2) Create an intermediate value for last year sales and subtract from this year's sales

```
LY Sales = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[$]),DATEADD(Data[Date],-1,YEAR))
VARIANCE = [$] - [LY Sales]
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data (in a usable format) and also current and desired output?

Comment: Sample data (or an attempt at it..lmk if format isn't usable)

| Year |: Region1 |: Region2 |: Region3 |: Region4 |: Total |
| 2019 |: 2809 |: 4143 |: 3661 |: 5864 |: 16478 
| 2020 |: 2175 |: 4379 |: 3986 |: 7252 |: 18794
| 2021 |: 3616 |: 4573 |: 4302 |: 8767 |: 21260
| 2022 |: 4088 |: 4817 |: 4623 |: 10360 |: 23889
| 2023 |: 4666 |: 5164 |: 4955 |: 12151 |: 26937
| 2024 |: 5274 |: 5506 |: 5315 |: 14751 |: 30848

Comment: |Year   |Region1 |Region2 |Region3 |Region4 |TOTAL|  <br/>
===============================================  <br/>
|2019 |2809 |4143 |3661 |5864 |16478|  <br/>
|2020 |2175 |4379 |3986 |7252 |18794|  <br/>
|2021 |3616 |4573 |4302 |8767 |21260|  <br/>
|2022 |4088 |4817 |4623 |10360 |23889|  <br/>
|2023 |4666 |5164 |4955 |12151 |26937|  <br/>
|2024 |5274 |5506 |5315 |14751 |30848|